# how to create layout so that Textview should auto adjust in android

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/notificationuserimage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/motherLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/notificationuserimage"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Request for traveling"
            android:textColor="#282e36"
            android:textSize="23px"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:text="asd has requested to travel with you"
            android:textColor="#282e36"
            android:textSize="23px" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/motherLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/notificationuserimage"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
                android:background="#10a7a2"
                android:text="Accept" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:background="#feffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:background="#10a7a2"
                android:text="Reject" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rejectedrequest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/revresetime"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Rejected"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/runnimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/revresetime"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rejectedrequest"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rejectedrequest"
                android:src="@drawable/drive"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/revresetime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="Just 5 Minute Ago"
                android:textColor="#8f939b"
                android:textSize="23px" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Given Code for List view item i am able display item in Listview .  my Current screen is Look Like this [image]

DeSire Screen :[image]

1.I am Unable to set date and time  2. there  is less width list-item   in Image which has not image date Moving left while it should auto adjust according to text  i have tried much unable to Control date and time textview autoset

Answer (score 0):

try using android:gravity tag to align your textViews and set paddings to seperate them:

```
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/yourId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"

                android:gravity="center_horizontal"

   />  



// android:gravity="left" to align to left
//  android:gravity="right" to align to right
```

Comment: in date time we have to apply this ?

Comment: yes, for example set gravity of date text to "center_horizontal" and set gravity of upper two textViews to left

Comment: http://snag.gy/Bz1sm.jpg  after edited code Date time is coming like this @NavinRaj Pandey

Comment: give a little right margin to layout holding date and also little right padding to date TextView , try changing values until it gets close enough to like unlike buttons

Comment: how to give margin layout holding

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

Comment: i am unable to set date coz after clcik its disappear and trvale request its not visible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61274/discussion-between-navinraj-pandey-and-anil).